# C# Overload ++ operator on function

Tags: c#, operators, log4net, indentation

I were looking around for a way to Indent my logging statements.
After a little googling and searching on SO i implemented an Indent class inside my wrapper for log4net to handle Indenting my logger statements.

Right now i need to call thees methods to increase and decrease the indenting.

```
_logger.Indent.Increase();
_logger.Debug(msg);
...
_logger.Indent.Decrease();
```

But having those two extra lines inside every function and so on pollutes the code unnecessarily imo. Are there some syntax candy way to do this in a nicer way, or should i just do it in a totally different way?

In any case this would be nice! :P

```
_logger.Debug(msg)++; //Increase indent for this logger statement and all to come.
_logger.Debug(msg)--; //Decrease Indent and logg...
```

Comment: I also just came over another problem, i'm using IoC Ninject, the logger is InSingeltonScope(); but its really not the same as having a static global singleton, because the indentCount inside gets reset to 0 inside every new class which takes logger in the constructor.. :/

Comment: What convention defines `++` as indent and `--` as unindent? I would strongly advise you not to go down this route as it will lead to hard to understand and maintain code. Future developers who come across your code and see all these `++` and `--` operators are likely to have a WTF moment.

Comment: I went with the LogScope implementation instead, and stayed with Increase and Decrease indent, instead of overloading operators ++ and -- :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have the `++` and `--` operators defined for the logger itself to increase and decrease indent respectively, and have `Debug` (and `Warn`, `Error` etc.) return the logger as well, then you could use the better, (but perhaps not perfect due to the parentheses in the pre-increment) syntax:

```
// Increment the indent, then log a message
(++_logger).Debug(msg);

// Log a message then decrement the indent
_logger.Debug(msg)--;
```

To me this makes slightly more sense in that using the pre-[inc|dec]rement operators you're saying "[inc|dec]rease the indent, **then** log a message", and the the post-[inc|dec]rement operators mean "log a message **then** [inc|dec]rease the indent".

Doing this also allows you to adjust the increment using:

```
++_logger;
--_logger;
```

You could also define a new class as follows:

```
public sealed class LogScope : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Logger _logger;

    public LogScope(Logger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        ++_logger;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        --_logger;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
_logger.Debug("This message is not indented");

using (new LogScope(_logger))
{
    // Anything logged within the using block will be indented
    _logger.Debug("This message is indented");
    using (new LogScope(_logger))
    {
        // LogScopes can be nested such that logging here will be double-indented
        _logger.Debug("This message is double-indented");
    }
    _logger.Debug("This message is back to single-indent");
}

// Logging here will revert to the original indent
_logger.Debug("This message is not indented");
```

Comment: awesome, I will get right on testing this out! I especially likes the LogScope idea! It will probably handle all try/catch blocks much better as well, less .decrease statements polluting the code

Comment: Is it possible to make this an Annotation, so that i would just have to write [Indent] over every function i want to be wrapped in a using(new LogScope()) {//code here} block?

Comment: @furier I'm not familiar with NInject, but it may support wrapping your objects so that any calls to an annotated method of the wrapped object have a LogScope around them, but this will only apply to calls from "outside" the wrapped object, which may or not be sufficient. You may want to ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

If you let the Debug function return the loggers Indent object, and inside the Indent class you have static implicit operators for ++ and --, you could do just that. Is that what you mean?

Comment: hmmmmm... it would work but i wouldn't indent the statement with the ++ operator just all those to come after... :/